# Retrieve a value from a user entry in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Completly new to mongoDB I'm trying to get the score field from a user in the "users" database that I have.

```
    public static DBCursor getScore(String username) {

    DBObject get = new QueryBuilder().put("name").is(username).get();

    return getUsers().find(get);

}
```

Once I get the user object, how can I get the attribute that I want?

Comment: you should investigate http://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Jongo. It makes your life much more easier. Here is the website: http://jongo.org/